# Time based thread synchronization in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Wondering if there is any time based synchronization in java. for example the below synchronization locks an object and waits until //my application processor finishes the task.

```
synchronize (myobject)
{
  //my application processor.
}
```

With the same, is there any way to say synchronize for only 1 min or 2 min.

```
synchronize (only for 1 min && object)
{
  //my application processor
}
```

or is there any other way in Java synchronization method.

P.S: 
  I don't want to run another ThreadManager to monitor the above.
  And I don't want to run while loop.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Holding a lock on an object for a minute is unlikely to be the right thing to do

Comment: Have a look at `ReentrantLock`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Comment: //Say if there is any problem in //my application processor (and loops) which would eventually hold other threads. In order to avoid that, I want all sync objects to be hold for the max of 1 min. If //my application processor finishes the task it would release else wait for another 1 min and then release.

Comment: If there's a 'problem' your application shouldn't just stall, an exception should be thrown causing the lock to be released.  The situation in which this isn't the case is if a dead-lock occurs, but that'd be down to a bug in the code, which should be fixed rather than ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor which provides various ways of scheduling a task to be performed/repeated in another thread at some specified time/times in the future.

Maybe you have a method that holds a lock for an extended period of time (almost always a bad idea), and you are asking how to abort the operation and release the lock if a time limit is reached.  There are a couple of ways you could do that depending on what it is that takes so much time.

But those are only guesses.  You haven't told us what the problem is that you are trying to solve.

---

Your example of using "synchronized" with a timeout does not make any sense.  The purpose of "synchronized" is to protect data structures from becoming corrupted.  That's not something you would want only for a limited time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to specify the minimum, using a timer and then adding a delay to fill in the extra.

But to specify the maximum amount of time that a thread can remain synchronized depends on how long it takes to complete its critical section. For instance if it were possible to specify a maximum of one minute, and the thread still has not finished executing its critical section, desynchronizing in the middle of the critical section would lead to an unstable state for the system.

Answer (score 1):

How about making you thread `wait()` and use a `Timer` to `notify()` your waiting object after 1min? So if your main process finishes it's work in time it would `notify()` the waiting thread and make it continue or otherwise it would be forced to work on after 1 min by the `Timer`.